# How to create an application like Alarm in android devices?

Tags: android, time, alarm

i want to create application that alarm is setted in it(i write it), but my question is that how can  i keep showing the time in the TextView until alarmming time?(i mean that if Back is pressed amd application is re openned, this TextView shows the alarm time).
for example now time is 11:38 AM, and i set an alarm on 15:13 and i have a TextView that its keeos showing alarm time (15:13) with this method, but now time my question is that how can i show this text (even though i exit from the app)until 15:13 o'clock and after  that it shows "+".
yhis method for converting time into text view (just for information):

```
private String convertTimeToString(long time) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);

    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    String timeSet;
    if (hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
        timeSet = "PM";
    } else if (hour == 0) {
        hour += 12;
        timeSet = "AM";
    } else if (hour == 12) {
        timeSet = "PM";
    } else {
        timeSet = "AM";
    }

    String minutes;
    if (minute < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minute;
    } else {
        minutes = String.valueOf(minute);
    }
    // Append in a StringBuilder
    return String.format("%s:%s %s", hour, minutes, timeSet);
}
```

i think this extra information is helpfull. thanks for your ansering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the alarm time in some sort of data storage.
Please take a look at the data storage options here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

I think, "SharedPreferences" is what will be best for you.
Slightly changing the official sample code, you will want something like this:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       String time = settings.getString("alarm_time", "12:00");
       mAlarmTextField.setText(time);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("alarm_time", mAlarmTextField.getText().toString());

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answering, i do it before, but my question is another the example that i write  above, please read it and help me,i need this code. thanks